# Query works ok in phpmyadmin but not with mysql_query php function

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have this sql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.uri uri
FROM resource r
INNER JOIN object o ON o.idResource = r.idResource
WHERE r.type = 2
AND r.idResource IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT r1.idResource
  FROM object o1
  INNER JOIN resource r1 ON r1.idResource = o1.idResource
  INNER JOIN class c1 ON c1.idClass = o1.idClass
  INNER JOIN property p2 ON p2.idResource = c1.idResource
  INNER JOIN object_value ov2 ON ov2.idProperty = p2.idProperty
                             AND ov2.idObject = o1.idObject
  WHERE c1.idResource = 364
  AND (p2.idProperty = 4 AND ov2.value LIKE '%dave%')
)
```

which works ok in phpmyadmin (mysql) but not in php code it gives timeout.

```
$result = mysql_query('$gquery') or die(mysql_error());
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't have `$gquery` in quotes. You should use

```
$result = mysql_query($gquery) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Yep, you're trying to execute '$gquery' as a String, but not the value of the variable.

Comment: Does your php file only have this line? Or is there more code that could be causing the problem?

Comment: Is in that exact line that it stops until it gives timeout (i have some echo for debug)
There is more code but I guess the problem has to do with the query, because when I change it, everything works fine.

Comment: Are you by any chance echoing the value of $gquery as it is passed to mysql_query?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: timeout issue. It was necessary to extend the timeout period. Sorry